# Equivalence relations and partial ordering: counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I have to prove that the number of equivalence relations is strictly lower than the number of partial orders over a set A of size >1.

I have managed to prove that the number of different antisymmetric relations over A is strictly higher than the number of symmetric relations over A.

I am struggling trying to connect this information with the reflexive and transitive parts they both share.

Anyway, I do not think that the problem is trying to find explicitly the number, since finding the number of different partial orders for in terms of the size of A seems tonbe a really hard problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Any equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\{1,2,...,n\}$ could be turned into a partial order by considering the intersection of $\sim$ and the usual total ordering.